# Getting checkbox values with getElementsByClassName for Mapbox

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, leaflet, mapbox, getelementsbyclassname

I'm working on something similar to that : http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-markers/

But with multiple "checkbox" like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' value='2008'>2008</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' value='2009'>2009</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' value='2010'>2010</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' value='2011'>2011</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' value='2012'>2012</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='active' id='filter-all'>Toutes les années</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm tyring to get the value linked to "checkbox" but it doesn't work.

```
var douze = ""; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('filter');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].className==="filter" && inputElements[i].checked){
          douze = inputElements[i].value;
          //console.warn(douze)
          break;
      }
}
```

It's trying to running here : http://temp.sharesand.info/prison/index5.html#

I'm trying to do it on plain JS, but i saw many versions with jquery.

Comment: at the begining i though that a simply `var douze = document.getElementsByClassName('filter').text;` was enough but not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akash Sarawagi did gratefuly the first part and the rest of the code has been changed a little bit.

```
div id='map-ui'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="selectyear(this);" name='2008'>2008</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="selectyear(this);" name='2009'>2009</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="selectyear(this);" name='2010'>2010</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="selectyear(this);" name='2011'>2011</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="selectyear(this);" name='2012'>2012</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="selectyear(this);" name='2013'>2013</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' class='active' id='filter-all' onclick="selectyear(this);" name="all">Toutes les années</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='map'></div>
<div id='info'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>

//loading background
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'n3b.map-xb4fp4td', { zoomControl: false })
    .setView([47.145894, 2.581787], 6);

//loading markers
var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer()
    .loadURL('http://temp.sharesand.info/prison/mortsPrisons.geojson')
    .addTo(map);

//filter per year
var year = "all";
function selectyear(me)
{
    var year = me.name;

        document.querySelector('#map-ui a.active').classList.remove('active');
        me.classList.add('active');

        markerLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
            if (year == "all") return true;
            return (f.properties['DateTime'].indexOf(year) != -1);
        });
};
```

Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

here is the required

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="abc(this);" name='2008'>2008</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="abc(this);" name='2009'>2009</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="abc(this);" name='2010'>2010</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="abc(this);" name='2011'>2011</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='filter' id='douze' onclick="abc(this);" name='2012'>2012</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' class='active' id='filter-all'>Toutes les années</a></li>
</ul>
```

and use this in js file

```
function abc(me)
{
    alert(me.name);
}
```

Comment: Seems a good start but i was "unable" to implement it to my code. I'm still stucked, but thanks for your help

Comment: okie do one this try alert(me.text); this should work. or you be more clear. cause i tested it and its working. So if you can explain your requirement then may be i can try to help you in better ways.

Comment: Thanks Akash for you're help. I've updated the code. The year is well return but it's not activating the filter.

Comment: You are most welcome. the code i have given you is just to get the selected text. In your code you were also trying to get the selected value. Nothing is written to make the filter work. You must write your business logic. Else explain and i will try